# jQuery and CSS :before

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-class

I'd like to use both the CSS :before pseudoclass and the jQuery .before() method to generate the same content (a `<li>` element) on a page for maximum browser compatibility (ie, both IE 6-7 AND other browsers with JavaScript disabled). Is this possible? Which will override the other?

Comment: `:before` is a pseudo-element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a class to the element (say, class="no-js") and remove it with javascript/jquery. Then style that class for the no-javascript case, then if, the user doesn't have javascript, that element will still have the style desired. Then, of course, if javascript is enabled, once you remove the class you can go ahead and do whatever you wish with javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the `<noscript>` tag around the css that has the :before on it. Just make sure it's css on the page and not linked.